# No matter the python code it won't run in atom

Tags: python-3.x

I recently started learning python and when starting my frist project using atom.io as my editor I tried running print('Hello World') and it won't run it shows me this [this is what appears after I press "F6" in order to run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc7Qn.png)

Comment: Looks like it ran successfully. Maybe it is printing somewhere else... What is the code you ran?

Comment: print('Hello World')